# Визуализация голосового сообщения

Tags: java, android

У голосового сообщения есть массив значений для визуализации, нужно сделать эту визуализацию. Как это лучше сделать?
Пример массива:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 3, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 5, 1, 3, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 5, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 7, 3, 3, 3, 13, 1, 16, 9, 2, 1, 2, 9, 6, 18, 13, 6, 5, 1, 29, 31, 6, 31, 5, 12, 10, 20, 16, 3, 10, 3, 12, 1, 4, 5, 9, 0, 9, 1, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 4, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 5, 3, 0, 1, 3, 1, 0, 0]
```

Желаемый результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Тут явно нужен кастомный вью. Могу написать, самому интересно, подождете?

Comment: Длина входного массива постоянна?

Comment: в основном 128, но еще заметил 256, скорее всего зависит от длины аудио

Comment: Посмотрите [библиотеки](https://android-arsenal.com/search?q=chart) для построения графиков. Вот [эта](https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3022) похожа на то, что вам нужно. Кое что придётся подправить, конечно.